# .onDelete and .searchable on the same view with CoreData on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I need help as I can't get both the search bar and object deleting to work simultaneously in my app. the data are managed through coredata. Leaving the code like this I get the invalid redeclarion of 'searchResults' error as there are two equal variables. How can i solve?

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Task.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.taskName, ascending: true),
    ]
) var searchResults: FetchedResults<Task>

private func deleteTask(at offset: IndexSet) {
    offset.forEach { index in
        let task = taskDetails.taskList[index]
        viewContext.delete(task)
        CoreDataManager.shared.save()
        viewModel.taskList = viewModel.getAllTaskList()
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection){
            ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { task in
                    TaskDetailsCell(viewModel: viewModel, task: task)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
}
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        .navigationTitle(taskDetails.categoryName)
        
}

   var searchResults: [Task] {
if searchText.isEmpty {
    return taskDetails.taskList
} else {
    return taskDetails.taskList.filter { $0.taskName!.contains(searchText) }
}
}
```

Comment: Change the name of `var searchResults: FetchedResults<Task>` to something else, like `var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>` you have 2 variables of the same name this one `var searchResults: [Task]` is the other one. they have to be unique.

Comment: If I change the name from the FetchedResults variable when the user deletes a row, the view does not update

Comment: Change both and adjust accordingly `taskDetails` isn't included but it likely references `searchResults` and is pulling the wrong object because it has the filtered list vs the full list stick with one source of truth, you seem to be lots of lists from lists and crossing them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do it in the same `View`, best make the `View` data structs as simple as possible and only do one thing. So instead, make a parent `View` that has the `searchable` and use the search text for a predicate in a `FetchRequest` and pass it into the child View. So structure it like this:

- View1 struct have `@State` searchText and searchable. Pass searchText to View2.
- View2 struct take `searchText` and create the predicate and use it to pass a `FetchRequest` to View3.
- View3 struct use the `@FetchRequest` to fetch the results and display in a `List`

For a full code sample see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073657/259521) to a similar question.